# How to identify the operating system in C during run time?

Tags: c, operating-system

I know how to identify the operating system in C during compile-time. For example, we can do something like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
<....>

#elif _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
<...>

#else
<...>

#endif
```

However, i would like to identify my operating system during run time. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do so instead of using macros?

Comment: First think if it would make any sense, as a program compiled for one OS is not usually compatible with others.

Comment: Maybe he wants to know if windows program is run on Linux under wine?

Comment: Does `uname` [the syscall] work for you? See: `man 2 uname` This is [somewhat] specific to posix, but the there is a compatibility layer/lib that exists for windows that _might_ have it. But, this means you'd already have to know a lot at compile time before using `uname`. The syscall is more useful for architecture, OS version [vs. type]

Comment: You really need to clarify this. There is no general api to identify the OS. And a binary for OS A is not guaranteed to run on OS B.

Comment: @CraigEstey That's Unix-specific, isn't it?

Comment: @CraigEstey: Is it in section 2 on your system? It is in section 3 on mine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have both 2 and 3 [linux/fedora] -- the 2 doc seems more complete (i.e. it shows the struct definition)

Comment: Just joking (kinda): `int isWindows(char **argv) { return !!strstr(argv[0], ".exe"); }`

Comment: @pmg Improvement for your program (?): `int isWindows(char **argv) { if (!!strstr(argv[0], ".exe")) abort(); return 0; }`

Comment: @0___________ wine is Windows it's the whole point of wine.

Comment: Another (far more complicated) possibility would be to do banner grabbing/OS fingerprinting on the localhost. For example, [nmap can do this on remote hosts](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html).

Comment: Another approach is: just ask the user. Present a list of options that the code supports. Have the user pick the one that best describes their system. Then put the answer into persistent storage somewhere, so that you don't need to ask again.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you are on a POSIX-compliant system and want the version information for the system, the `uname` routine provides that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct utsname name;
    uname(&name);
    printf("Operating system name = %s.\n", name.sysname);
    printf("Node (network) name = %s.\n", name.nodename);
    printf("Release level = %s.\n", name.release);
    printf("Version level = %s.\n", name.version);
    printf("Machine = %s.\n", name.machine);
}
```

On my current system, that prints:

```
Operating system name = Darwin.
Node (network) name = Hither.local.
Release level = 18.7.0.
Version level = Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Jun 22 19:37:08 PDT 2021; root:xnu-4903.278.70~1/RELEASE_X86_64.
Machine = x86_64.
```

The `sysctlbyname` routine may also provide information of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

You may do this:

```
enum OS get_os(void) {
#ifdef WIN32
    return OS_WINDOWS;
#elif _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
    return OS_POSIX;
#else
    return OS_UNKNOWN;
#endif
}
```

Operating system defines ABI. The code compiled for one OS cannot run on another. Thus it doesn't make much sense to have such function.

Comment: It is still compile time, even when you wrapped it

Comment: @0___________ you may call this function at runtime. Right?

Comment: It does not matter. it is still compile time

Comment: @0___________ If you can compute something at compile time it implies you can compute the same thing at runtime. So I don't really get your point.

Comment: Simple: there no code determining OS in your function. It simply makes no sense.

Comment: @0___________ What you are saying is not true. There obviously is such code. It's quite simple but it's there. Determining OS doesn't take much code at runtime as it's constant.

Comment: @Nolan The distinction is pretty simple. Once this program is compiled, it can "determine" only one single OS. Obviously the OP knows this method and is not asking about it.

Comment: @Nolan Imagine two different OSes, but with binary compatibility. I could send the binary from one to the other, and they would execute. However, your code would generate wrong output in the second OS. Say you compile at OSA, send it to OSB and run it. At OSB your program would display "OSA".

Comment: @EnzoFerber I can imagine this but I cannot infer this from the question. The operating systems generally are not binary compatible.

Comment: The point about binary-compatible OS'es is well taken, but: I was about to give the same answer as Nolan did.  I guess it comes down to a question of what you mean by "operating system" — but for one way of looking at it, the answer to the question "which system was it compiled for?" is valid, and of course that's what this answer gives.  If two "different systems (a) have the same API and (b) are binary-compatible, I'm not 100% sore we can say they're "different".

Comment: My point is that while it may be obvious to 0___________, Eugene Sh., and Enzo Ferber that this is not the answer they would want, it is not obvious to me that this is not the (or an) answer that the OP would want.  I don't see it as a wrong answer.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think it is obvious that the OP is well aware of this method. It is there, in the question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You've said that twice now (I saw it the first time), but: I think it's very hard to know what is or isn't obvious to an OP, which is why I think this was an eminently worthwhile answer to post, if only to clarify what the OP really does or doesn't want.

Comment: I agree that this is a useful answer, different from the other but quite clearly within the realm of what the OP was asking for, until he tells us differently.